# How to automatically update database from dataset change

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, sql-server-ce

I have a database table that loads to a **DataTable** object which is binded to multiple UIElements such as **DataGrid**, **ComboBox**, **TextBoxes** etc's **ItemsSource** property. Is there a way where I am implement a "watch dog" that constantly check if the DataTable or DataSet has been changed and automatically update the database on a separate thread?

My goal is to eliminate the need for the client having to manually trigger a "Save" event to propagate these changes to the database, and that the database is always in-sync with the data in DataSet/DataTable. Please also suggest if this is a good practice or is there a better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataTable object has many events that get triggered on row data change.
You could use RowChanged/RowChanging, RowDeleted/RowDeleting

[See a full documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You could add an event handler for a RowChanging event in this simple way

```
yourTable.RowChanging += new DataRowChangeEventHandler(yourRowChangingHandler);
```

and then add the handler

```
private void yourRowChangingHandler(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Action={0}", e.Action);
}
```

where the [Action property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowaction.aspx) is an enum that describes the operation

Comment: but how do I constantly "listen" to changes in DataSet?

Comment: Well, I am not sure to understand you correctly. When you attach an event handler to every table that you are interested to 'autoupdate', you don't 'listen' to anything, the event will be fired by the framework when your user changes anything in the gridview/combobox/control bounded to the dataset/datatable.

Comment: Because there are too many events associated with changing DataTables/DataSet, instead of checking RowChanging in each event handler, I like to have a separate, parallel thread that constantly listen to changes in the DataTable and propagate the changes to database. But I'm not sure how to proceed, even conceptually..

Comment: Well, this is not an easy task. (And also with a parallel thread you need always a way to know when something change in you table and AFAIK this could be done only from the event raised by the table itself). For conceptual info on threading I could suggest [this link](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)